# How do I fetch this from two different table in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have two tables state and city
state table has two column

```
state_id | state_name
---------|-----------
1        | Alabama
2        | Alaska
3        | Arizona
```

and City table has two column as well

```
state_name | city_name
-----------|----------
1          |
1          |
1          |
2          |
2          |
3          |
```

#### Controller

```
function city()
{
    $data = array();
    $data['states']=$this->state_model->state_query();  
    $data['cities']=$this->cities_model->cities_query();  
    $this->load->view('city', $data);
}
```

#### Model

```
public function state()
{
    $this->db->select('state_name');
    $this->db->from('state');
    $this->db->join('city', 'city.state_name = state.state_name');
    $result = $this->db->get();
}
```

#### View

```
<?php foreach ($cities as $city) { ?>
<?php echo $city->city_name; ?>
<?php echo $city->state_name; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

the above code is the controller, model, and view respectively. The issue is that I want to echo state_name but not working, the city name is displaying as expected. Please, I need suggestion on what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your Model Should Be:

```
public function state()
{
    $this->db->select('s.state_name as state,c.city_name as city, c.state_name as state_id');
    $this->db->from('state as s');
    $this->db->join('city as c', 'c.state_name = s.state_id ');
    $result = $this->db->get();

$data = $result->result_array();

    if(isset($data) && !empty($data))
    {
        return $data;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Your Controller Should be:

```
public function city()
{   
    $this->load->model('your_model');       
    $city_state_data = $this->your_model->state();      

    //  I have just added example of getting data from model to controller 
    // and then passing it to view. You need to use it as you need

    $this->load->view('your_view', ['city_state_data' => $city_state_data]);
}
```

#### View:

```
<?php foreach ($city_state_data as $single_city_state) { ?>
<?php echo $single_city_state['state']; ?>
<?php echo $single_city_state['city']; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: If I do this <?php echo $city->state_name; ?> It will display the figures however I want the names from the state column

Comment: pls what is the best way to display it on the view since I may want to display fields from the both tables

Answer (score 0):

**Model**

```
    public function state()
{
    $this->db->select('state.state_name as state_tbl1, city.state_name as state_tbl2, city.city_name');
    $this->db->join('city', 'city.state_name = state.state_name');
    $result = $this->db->get('state'); 
    return $result->result();
}
```

**Controller**

```
function city()
{
    $data['states']=$this->state_model->state();    
    $this->load->view('city', $data);
}
```

**View**

```
<?php foreach ($states as $city) { 
echo $city->city_name;
echo $city->state_tbl1;
echo $city->state_tbl2;
} ?>
```